# How to handle singleton with multiple server instances

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a standard way of handling the singleton pattern when a system uses multiple instances of servers? Say I have a token I need to refresh every 30 minutes, but I only get 2 refreshes an hour. With a single instance, I might use a singleton to store my token on a Client class. But if I had 5 instances of my server, wouldn't this render this design insufficient? Since all modern systems use multiple servers... is the singleton pattern still relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scenario. But a pattern like singleton applies to one application/executable/assembly. If you run your exe file multiple times, of course each one will have its own unique instance. Do you mean you need a unique instance of a token provider service? Do you need all servers to share the same token pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern systems use a single DB at the backend. There are many ways to ensure that a given operation happens only once.

- Each server performs the operation periodically. But only the first update is reflected in the DB.
- A data set is divided between services using some partitioning algorithm. Then the server that is responsible for a specific key performs the update.
- An external timer service makes a single cal per key. One of the instances receives it through a load balancer.

The last two approaches work even without a shared DB.